# Github for windows sync failure

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using Github GUI for windows, I have only master and no more branch, my last commit fails to sync. I was thinking `revert` command does undo the commit but I was wrong, now by gitbash on project folder I used `git status` command and this is the result

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1)'
```

I think the problem is by the special characters I used in commit description.

ahead by 2 commits, one is my original commit and one is its revert.

how should I solve the problem?

I also contacted support@github ;

1. Open Explorer (i.e. any folder), and type `%LocalAppData%` in the
   address bar
2. Delete the GitHub folder
3. In the same address bar, type `%AppData%`
4. Delete the GitHub folder there too

But did not work!

Comment: Change the commit messages? https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/

Comment: if one is the initial, and the other is the revert of it, just blat the thing and start over?

Comment: @Randy I changed the commit message but again the same problem

Comment: @DevDonkey the Github windows has "undo most recent commit", I did that, and changed message but again the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

support@github answered me:
got ot `%LocalAppData%` after that to Github folder and delete `PortableGit_****`

and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your *branch* if you want to be sure this will work;

1. Clone the *repository* again to another folder
2. Update the sources that you want to change in your new *commit*
3. *Commit* those changes
4. *Push* those changes to your *repository*

Comment: I did all, I think the problem is by the Github application for windows. by command CLI I could push the commit but again for new commits with windows app I face the same problem

Comment: can it be something from anti virus? my ESET smartSecurity got updated just today and this is today that I have faced the problem

Comment: @AmirHM I don't expect that to be the issue. Maybe you could try if it works on another machine? Send your source code there, and push it? If that doesn't work,  maybe your source-code encoding has issues.